# How To Combine KnockoutJS With HTML Tags - Specifically BootStrap

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have been using Bootstrap for a while now and love it.  Saves me a bunch of time.  I just started with KnockoutJS and as it happens, I have to combine the two at a rather granular level.  My Knockout object(s) are filling a results table.  When I just want the values (like Name) it is working great.  However, I want to put an icon (icon-pencil for you Bootstrap people) in front of my link so it stands out as something to edit.  I am using ASP.Net (not MVC) but I suspect that is not an issue.

Here is some code that works (but has no icon):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtEditGenerator" runat="server" data-bind="text: GeneratorName, click: function() { EditGeneratorClick(GeneratorID) }"></asp:LinkButton>
```

However, I want to add the following code just in front of the "GeneratorName" to get me the pencil icon.  I need it to be within the text property so it is part of the LinkButton:

```
<i class='icon-pencil'></i>
```

Combining them in the bind-data (as follows) throws a parsing error:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtEditGenerator" runat="server" data-bind="text: <i class='icon-pencil'></i> GeneratorName, click: function() { EditGeneratorClick(GeneratorID) }"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Aside from creating a new property on my object that combines the two values, is there a way to do this with the Knockout binding?

Comment: What does the resulting HTML markup need to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something along these lines:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtEditGenerator" runat="server" click: function() { EditGeneratorClick(GeneratorID) }">
    <i class='icon-pencil'></i>
    <span data-bind="text: GeneratorName"></span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Alternatively, you can put the `<i>` element before the `<asp:LinkButton>`. The solution above allows you to click either on the icon or on the text to trigger the button.

Comment: That is exactly what I wound up doing.  :)